# Remove default padding inside Slider component of Jetpack Compose

Tags: slider, padding

Below is the code and the image with background to see the padding I want to remove

```
private fun SimpleSlider() {

var sliderValue by remember { mutableStateOf(5.5f) }

Slider(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Magenta),
    value = sliderValue,
    onValueChange = { sliderValue_ ->
        sliderValue = sliderValue_
    },
    onValueChangeFinished = {
        // this is called when the user completed selecting the value
        Log.d("MainActivity", "sliderValue = $sliderValue")
    },
    valueRange = 0f..10f
)

Text(text = sliderValue.toString())}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it like this:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
    Slider()...
}
```

This will remove the 48dp min size restriction for the slider.

Comment: This is not working any other way.